# Trouble with Nested Do Loops

Tags: procedural-programming

I have:

```
myres = {};
Do[
 Do[
  Append[myres, {j, i}], {i, 1, 3}
  ],
 {j, 1, 5}
 ]
```

However, when I run the code and then enter:

```
myres
```

I get:

(* { } *)

Why is it empty? Can someone explain my misunderstanding? Also, could someone suggest some lines in the code that will show some intermediate results as to what is happening?

Comment: Use AppendTo, it changes list structure permanently.

Comment: Rather use Table. Avoid imperative programming in Mathematica.

Comment: @Rorschach Aha! I should have had `myres = Append[myres, {j, i}]`. Of course, AppendTo is more efficient. And yes, I like Table better as well, but I am trying to work on some procedural programming style.

Comment: `AppendTo` is not efficient, try to run your program with `AppendTo` for say `i=300,j=500`. And then try `Table` with same values. Mathematica has some inherent problems, like any other system.

Comment: Duplicate of [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19804/57) to our big "Pitfalls" question.

Comment: `Sow` and `Reap` can be more useful than `Table` in more complicated cases (e.g., if a list item in not always generated in each iteration).

Answer (score 1):

Append is not a mutator. You either need `myres = Append[...]` or `AppendTo[...]`.

As far as monitoring, you could simply add Print statements, or try [Monitor](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Monitor.html).